# Why Ident_Current returns null but Scope_Identity does?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It returns null, why? The `IDENT_CURRENT` part but it works well with `Scope_Identity`, why ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo]. [InsertComplaints] 
    @ComplaintCode varchar(50),
    @ComplaintType_ID smallint,
    @RecievingMode_ID smallint,
    @Subject varchar(100),
    @ComplainantID smallint,
    @District_ID smallint,
    @AddressedTo varchar(50),
    @DiaryNo varchar(50),
    @User_ID int,
    @Status_ID smallint,
    @RecievedDate smalldatetime,
    @IGRemarks varchar(MAX) = null,
    @PsoRemarks varchar(MAX) =null,
    @FinalDecision varchar(250)=null,
    @AgainstDist_ID smallint,
    @HomePS_ID smallint,
    @AgainstPS_ID smallint, 
    @Name varchar(75),
    @DesigID int,
    @ForwardedBy smallint,
    @SMS_ID int = 0,
    @result bit output,
    @ID int output
AS
BEGIN
   Begin Try
        insert into dbo.Complaints 
        values (
        @ComplaintCode,
        @ComplaintType_ID,
        @RecievingMode_ID ,
        @Subject,
        @ComplainantID ,
        @District_ID ,
        @AddressedTo ,
        @DiaryNo,
        @User_ID,
        @Status_ID,
        @RecievedDate,
        @IGRemarks,
        @PsoRemarks,
        @FinalDecision,
        @AgainstDist_ID,
        @HomePS_ID,
        @AgainstPS_ID,
        @Name ,
        @DesigID,
        @ForwardedBy,
        @SMS_ID
        ) 

        Set @result = @@ROWCOUNT 

        Set @ID = IDENT_CURRENT('ComplaintID') --SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
        Select @ID
   End Try
   Begin Catch
        Set @result=0
   End Catch
END
```

I want to get a last inserted `id` from particular table such that `complaintID` from complaints table but it doesn't return any but null. Help !

Comment: Does `SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` work? It should - but you need to use `SELECT` instead of `SET`, I believe ...

Comment: yes scope_Identity works fine

Comment: Why do you want to use `IDENT_CURRENT`? That will return the latest ID used in the latest insert (committed or not), not the one *you* just inserted in this procedure.

Comment: @Luaan then what should i use ? @@Identity is fine ? should i use ?

Comment: my problem is to get the latest inserted value of record being inserted only by this procedure ? in only this table i.e. complaint

Comment: Well, what's wrong with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`? It should give you exactly what you want - the last identity value inserted in a given scope.

Comment: right i am confused by reading different definitions of ScopeIDentity, @Identity etc. so that's y

Comment: The difference between `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `@@IDENTITY` is that `@@IDENTITY` is not limited to the scope - so if you've got an insert trigger in there that inserts a new row, it will return the identity of that row, not the original one. `IDENT_CURRENT` simply returns the last identity on a given table, regardless of any scope.

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) the IDENT_CURRENT function will return null if the calling user does not have enough permissions on this object.
Another possibility is that your object name is wrong, i see you're doing your insert with the dbo prefix. Maybe that will help.

Comment: i do have a permission since i am updating inserting but this one doesn't work i changed it a bit but still no luck. i.e. Select @ID= Ident_Current('Complaints.ComplaintID')

Comment: I believe you can have insert permission but not view metadata permission. If you can test it i would grant the user executing this code ownership of that table(or making him db admin for a few minutes) to make sure it has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: And as for the correct name i didnt mean add the identity but rather the full database name. For example : (Ident_Current('MyDatabase.dbo.Complaints')